# Kubernetes 1.8 Cannot delete pod

Tags: kubernetes

I've a kubernetes 1.8. I've deploy a lots of services but I've problem remove some pods, it's never delete.

This is the pod describe:

```
Name:                      project-settlement-api-798c8b6688-ldclr
Namespace:                 project
Node:                      10.93.96.208/10.93.96.208
Start Time:                Fri, 10 Nov 2017 18:39:08 -0300
Labels:                    app=project-settlement-api
                           pod-template-hash=3547462244
                           run=project
Annotations:               kubernetes.io/created-by={“kind”:“SerializedReference”,“apiVersion”:“v1",“reference”:{“kind”:“ReplicaSet”,“namespace”:“project”,“name”:“project-settlement-api-798c8b6688”,“uid”:“955c2781-c65f-11e7-ba5...
Status:                    Terminating (expires Fri, 17 Nov 2017 10:25:24 -0300)
Termination Grace Period:  0s
IP:                        
Created By:                ReplicaSet/project-settlement-api-798c8b6688
Controlled By:             ReplicaSet/project-settlement-api-798c8b6688
Containers:
  project-settlement-api:
    Container ID:  
    Image:          
   Image ID:      
    Port:           <none>
    State:          Terminated
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 +0000
      Finished:     Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE:  docker
    Mounts:
      /opt from project-volume (rw)
      /var/project from project-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-qw23t (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          False
  PodScheduled   True 
Volumes:
  project-volume:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  project-pvc
    ReadOnly:   false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     <none>
Events:          <none>
```

And this is the pod list where you can find 3 pods that cannot delete:

```
NAME                                        READY     STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
project-companies-api-5847b84599-6tpbq      0/1       Terminating   0          9m
project-companies-api-5847b84599-ph4xl      1/1       Running       0          4m
project-companies-api-5847b84599-z5vr2      0/1       Terminating   3          11m
project-middleware-85888df786-8nxlj         1/1       Running       0          14d
project-settlement-api-5cb5d5859d-qrq8b     1/1       Running       0          2m
project-settlement-api-798c8b6688-ldclr     0/1       Terminating   0          20d
project-transactions-api-779cd489b7-xvgd8   1/1       Running       0          14d
project-users-api-7d7c5cd99d-bqg88          1/1       Running       0          14d
project-web-57c869d6fc-7qpk5                1/1       Running       0          14d
monitor-app-6455cf9dcf-p4ww4                1/1       Running       0          16m
```

I've try a lot command in order to delete it but nothing happend. kubectl delete po/mypod --grace-period=0 --force --namespace mynamespace

Anybody can help me?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you are using a Deployment API Object. Therefore, if you remove the pod it will be recreated. Try the following:

```
kubectl  get deployments
```

Get the deployment id and execute

```
kubectl delete deployment DEP_ID
```

Then it will be removed. If there is no deployment check replicasets as well

Comment: The problem is that the POD in terminating state never dissapear, if I've delete the deployment the pod stay here.

Comment: I've delete the deploy and replicaset but the pod stay:  po/middleware-fd966f865-km5zz   0/1       Unknown   0          19h

Comment: Try restarting kubelet

Comment: I've restart kubelet but I've only delete de deployment and replicaset, the pod still here.

Comment: If you do not have other deployments, I would advise you to delete the etcd data folder, but first DO make a backup.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the docker daemon on the master node

This issue might be related to what you are experiencing:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/51835